# What I'm doing wrong ? nothing's changed when I click on modify to update a row in a table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, razor, sql-update, asp.net-webpages

I'm creating a web application to manage a medical office.... and I'm creating a page to modify the phone number and the address of each patient

and whenever I enter the new info and click on the button Modify nothing's change and it doesn't show any error.

what I'm doing wrong ? I'm lost, this is my code

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@{
Database db = Database.Open("CM");
var sql = "select * from patients where Id_p='"+Request["p"]+"'";
dynamic M_Patient = db.QuerySingle(sql);

if (Request["Modify"]!=null)
{
var sql1="update patients set Tel="+Request["N_Tel"]+", Adresse='"+Request["N_Adresse"]+"' where Id_P= '"+Request["p"]+"';";
db.Execute(sql1);
Response.Redirect("Patient.cshtml");
}
}
```

Comment: Follow the asp.net method for prevention of SQL vulnerabilities. Update question after doing this. Double check for errors errors. Are you getting redirected to Patient.cshtml? If not it might be due to `Modify`

Comment: yes, when I fill the two input field it redirects to Patient.cshtml but it shows just the old info, not the updated info